# What song played right after the OP of Parasyte Episode 10?

Tags: music, parasyte

Does anyone know the song played as soon as the OP ends in the beginning of episode 10? It's not listed in the soundtrack and I can't find it anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

Parasyte has some OSTs which were not released in the Vol.1 
They were expected to be released in a special edition but idk what happened.

Here is the OST I think you're talking about

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Tvj46wuhM3o